# Getting error code malformed_query when tried to query eventlog through REST in workbench

Tags: rest, workbench, eventlogfile

I tried to query Dashboard activity from event log. So I am using workbench and tried to pull it but getting error code malformed_query.

I am using REST explorer  and my query is

```
/services/data/v35.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+,+EventType+,+LogDate+,+LogFileLength+,+LogFile+FROM+EventLogFile+WHERE+EventType+=+'/services/data/v36.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+,+EventType+,+LogDate+,+LogFileLength+,+LogFile+FROM+EventLogFile+WHERE+EventType+=+'Dashboard'.
```

Comment: try `EventType+IN+:+`

Comment: You have to somehow escape the single quotes around 'Dashboard' at the end and put a closing quote at the end (so it should end with something like `WHERE+EventType+=+\'Dashboard\''`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this.. You are adding two times `/services/data/v35.0` in your query

```
/services/data/v35.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+,+EventType+,+LogDate+,+LogFileLength+,+LogFile+FROM+EventLogFile+WHERE+EventType+=+'Dashboard'
```